# Bash. Variable visibility and lifetime

Tags: linux, bash, function, variables, visibility

I'm not experienced in bash and I've met a case that makes me perplexed. It's an example of such a case:

```
f1()
{
  ar+=(1)
  ar+=(3)
  ar+=(2)
  var="var value"
  echo "0"
}

f2()
{

   res=$(f1)
   echo -------point 1--------
   for i in ${ar[@]}; do
       echo "El $i"
   done
   echo $var

   echo -------point 2--------
   f1>/dev/null
   for i in ${ar[@]}; do
       echo "El $i"
   done
   echo $var
}

f2
```

This script produces the following result:

```
-------point 1--------

-------point 2--------
El 1
El 3
El 2
var value
```

As you can see, the function f1 was called in two different ways and they give very different implications. In the first call the array and variable declared in f1 apparently destroyed. 
In the second way the array and the variable were saved.

Does anybody can explain it to me or give me a link to appropriate manual?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do this:

```
res=$(f1)
```

You create a subshell, execute `f1` inside the subshell and store the output to the variable `$res`. Any variables created within that subshell are lost after it has closed.

When you do this:

```
f1>/dev/null
```

You execute `f1`within the current shell. The variables that are created within the function are in the global scope, so can be accessed subsequently.